# How to connect to multiple hosts in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node js app built on express and mongoose. Until now, i was using mongoose.connect(uri, options) to make a db connection. But from now on, i want to be able to connect to multiple databases on multiple hosts. Everything is working fine if i'm on the same host ( i use mongoose.createConnection(uri, options) ). For production databases stored on the same host or for localhost databases everything is fine. The problem appears if i try to connect to one localhost database and one remote database, instead of both on the same host.

- Does anyone knows what can be wrong?
- Is there a config option that i'm missing?

DbConnection file:

```
this.sharedDbConnection = this.mongooseConnection.createConnection('sharedDb');
this.defaultDbConnection = this.mongooseConnection.createConnection('mongodb');
```

MongooseConnection file:

```
function getConnectionUrl(config) {

    return 'mongodb://' + config.user + ':' + config.password + '@' + config.host + ':' + config.port + '/' + config.dbName;
}

MongooseConnection.prototype.createConnection = function(dbName) {

    var connection = this.mongoose.createConnection(getConnectionUrl(this.config[dbName]), this.mongooseConfig, function(err) {

        if(err) {

            console.log(err);

        } else {

            console.log('connected with createConnection on ', dbName);

        }

    });

    return connection;

};
```

MongooseConfig:

```
{
    server: {
        poolSize:      10,
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1
        }
    },
    db:     {
        numberOfRetries:  10,
        retryMiliSeconds: 1000
    },
    auth:   false
};
```

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: nothing. i don't receive an error. it appears as connected to both servers. But for one of them it returns an empty array for all the requests.